# Validation Rule with $Profile

Tags: profile, validation-rule

I want to create a Validation Rule that must fire when Account Name is changed and profile is different from `ProfileId_1` and `ProfileId_2`.

I tried with different validation rules, but none works:

1. `ISCHANGED(Name) && ($Profile.Id != '00e24000000YVsFAAW' && $Profile.Id != '00e240000011Ib0AAE')`
2. `ISCHANGED(Name) && ( contains($Profile.Name, 'System Administrator') && contains($Profile.Name, 'Profile2') )`
3. `ISCHANGED(Name) && ($Profile.Name != 'Profile2' && $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator')`
4. `ISCHANGED(Name) && ($User.ProfileId != '00e24000000YVsFAAW' && $User.ProfileId != '00e240000011Ib0AAE')`

This part of the rule `ISCHANGED(Name)` works perfect, but when I try to check profiles it does not work. Ids and names have been checked in the database and are correct. Also, I tried to test them separately, first checking Name and then checking profiles. Profiles checking never works.

Comment: Never ever *ever* use hard-coded Ids. Even in a Validation Rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking profile names/IDs have always been problematic in validation rules. You shouldn't do it. Instead, create a [Custom Permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5), assign it to the two profiles, then you can easily check for that:

```
ISCHANGED(Name) && NOT($Permission.Change_Account_Name)
```